# Fluent Nhibernate Oracle Identifier Too Long - Alias Name Issue

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent, ora-00942

I've tried to do that.

```
HasManyToMany<YechidotDoarInGroup>(x => x.Col_yig) 
  .Table("PigToYig") 
  .ChildKeyColumn("YIG_GROUP_RECID") 
 .ParentKeyColumn("PIG_GROUP_RECID");
```

but I've got:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I am trying to establish  HasManyToMany connection not by ID , but by 
some other property .

First I've got - too long message.  When I've tried to enter my own Table name as an alias , it's not recognized. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Table() method before all of your mapping declaration.

```
public EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("EMPLOYEE");
        // your declaration
        Id(x => x.IdEmployee);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem may well be this:

```
.Table("PigToYig")
```

Oracle object names are, by default, in UPPER case.  However, Oracle applies names in double-quotes in the given case.  In other words, if your table has the default naming you may need to pass in this instead ...

```
.Table("PIGTOYIG")
```

It depends how NHibernate converts those variables into SQL (I'm not familiar with NHibernate).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Tried it with Uppercase , still no solution .
The oracle doesn't recognize the table name . 
By logic , the table doesn't exist in DB , it's being created by the FNH itself and when it tries to run the query it fails with -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
Do you have some other leads on the subject ?

Answer (score 1):

> Cause:    The table or view entered does
>   not exist, a synonym that is not
>   allowed here was used, or a view was
>   referenced where a table is required.
>   Existing user tables and views can be
>   listed by querying the data
>   dictionary. Certain privileges may be
>   required to access the table. If an
>   application returned this message, the
>   table the application tried to access
>   does not exist in the database, or the
>   application does not have access to
>   it.
>
> Action:
>   Check each of the following:
>
> ```
>  * the spelling of the table or view name.
>  * that a view is not specified where a table is required.
>  * that an existing table or view name exists.
> ```

[source ora-code.com](http://ora-00942.ora-code.com/)