# Oracle issue: ORA-00972: identifier is too long / NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, nhibernate, ora-00972

This is the query performed by NHibernate against the Oracle database:

```
select
    compteurra0_.NO_SEQ_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ as NO1_2_,
    compteurra0_.TXT_INFO_COMPL as TXT2_2_,
    compteurra0_.TYP_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ as TYP3_2_,
    compteurra0_.VAL_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ as VAL4_2_,
    compteurra0_.VAL_CPTE_ATNDU as VAL5_2_,
    compteurra0_.ID_UTIL_CREAT_OCC as ID6_2_,
    compteurra0_.DHC_OCC as DHC7_2_,
    compteurra0_.NO_SEQ_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ as NO8_2_ 
from
    ESO.ESO_V_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ compteurra0_
```

When I perform this query against the database, it returns an Oracle error:

- **`ORA-00972: identifier is too long`**

I have searched the Internet and found that a bug was reported back in 2005 using NHibernate and Oracle: [`Oracle issue: ORA-00972: identifier is too long`](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-135)

- **Has this really been solved?**

I have found two other related SO questions stating resolutions using Hibernate in Java.

- Can the same be done using NHibernate?
- If so, how to make it work?

  1. [`hibernate oracle identifier is too long ORA-00972`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414094/hibernate-oracle-identifier-is-too-long-ora-00972)
  2. [`Fluent Nhibernate Oracle Identifier Too Long - Alias Name Issue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127581/fluent-nhibernate-oracle-identifier-too-long-alias-name-issue)

> **`CompteurRapportAcces.cs`**

```
public class CompteurRapportAcces : AuditableEntity {
    public virtual string InformationComplementaire { get; set; }
    public virtual RapportAccesInformation Rapport { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeCompteur Type { get; set; }
    public virtual int Valeur { get; set; }
    public virtual int ValeurAttendue { get; set; }

    public enum TypeCompteur {
        Ordonnance = 1,            
        Delivrance = 2,
        OrdonnanceElectronique = 3,
        InscriptionRegistreDesRefus = 4
    }
}
```

> **`CompteurAccesRapport.hbm.xml`**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="QueContientMonDSQ.Model" assembly="QueContientMonDSQ">
  <class name="CompteurRapportAcces" table="ESO_V_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ" schema="ESO">
    <id name="Id" column="NO_SEQ_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="sequence-identity">
        <param name="sequence">ESO_NO_SEQ_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ</param>
        <param name="schema">ESO</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="InformationComplementaire" column="TXT_INFO_COMPL" type="String" length="1000" />
    <property name="Type" column="TYP_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ" type="Int32" />
    <property name="Valeur" column="VAL_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ" type="Int32" />
    <property name="ValeurAttendue" column="VAL_CPTE_ATNDU" type="Int32" />
    <property name="Creator" column="ID_UTIL_CREAT_OCC" type="String" length="15" />
    <property name="Created" column="DHC_OCC" />
    <many-to-one name="Rapport" class="RapportAccesInformation" column="NO_SEQ_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> **`hibernate.cfg.xml`**

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory name="QueContientMonDSQ">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<id name="Id" column="NO_SEQ_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="sequence-identity">
    <param name="sequence">ESO_NO_SEQ_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_DSQ</param>
    <param name="schema">ESO</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

The length of identifier(column name) `NO_SEQ_CPTE_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ` must be <= 30.

Comment: +1 Duh! I took this column name from another table and only changed a few characters without noticing that the `INFO_` part was not part of this sequence name. I made the verification after your call. Thanks a lot for this! It's a shame I didn't figure it out myself! ;-) Thanks! (I would accept your answer, but SO won't let me before 9 minutes.)

Comment: Sure..!! Sometimes different eyes are required to find tiny bugs, when we do big things! :)

Comment: So true! That is what I like about SO and pair-programming. Thanks for this remark on the big things! ;) (16 seconds until approval!)